# Finding a more effective solution to using if statements with multiple outcomes

Tags: c#, if-statement, selection

I am using C# to make a script that can handle and use FEN string notations to create unique chess positions. Given a string, it has to check each character to see whether it is a r, n, k, q, p etc to figure out which piece needs to be drawn. To do this, I use a lot of if statements and was wondering if there was any simpler/cleaner way to check the character against multiple values and give separate outputs.

```
    if(c == 'r')
    {
       Instantiate(blackRook, new Vector2(gridX, gridY), Quaternion.identity);
       gridX += 1;
    }
    else if(c == 'n')
    {
       Instantiate(blackKnight, new Vector2(gridX, gridY), Quaternion.identity);
       gridX += 1;
    }
    else if(c == 'p')
    {
       Instantiate(blackPawn, new Vector2(gridX, gridY), Quaternion.identity);
       gridX += 1;
    }
```

As you can see, there's clearly a lot of repetition here. I thought about using a function to cover all instantiations of all pieces including increasing the other variable, but I would still have to check which piece is which and what the appropriate response should be.

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try extracting model, e.g. as a dictionary:

```
//TODO: Put right type name instead of 'Piece'
Dictionary<char, Piece> blackPieces = new() {
  {'r', blackRook},
  {'n', blackKnight},
  {'p', blackPawn},
  // Add more pieces (Bishop, Queen, King...) if required
};

...

if (blackPieces.TryGetValue(c, out var piece)) {
  Instantiate(piece, new Vector2(gridX, gridY), Quaternion.identity);
  gridX += 1;
}
```

Comment: Under the hood still the same technically, but there is no more efficient way to do what he is doing but nice approach.

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist: if you have just *several* options to choose from there's nothing to improve; however if we have *a lot of* options, hashing is more efficient: `O(1)` vs. `O(n)`

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I was considering using a dictionary but wasn't sure how to implement it, this is a great help. I was also considering using a switch statement/case - would this be effective?

Comment: Conditional to polymorphism: https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism